# Can mean() function show probability of cumulative distribution function?

Tags: r, statistics, mean, cdf

I was doing my assignment, and I found something strange.
I did this code for question #1.

```
x <- heights$height[heights$sex=="Male"]
```

and the next question is like this:

> "We will define a function "CDF" like following:   `CDF <- function(a) {mean(x<=a)}`
> Explain why the CDF function is Cumulative Distribution Function."

I get the idea of the cumulative distribution function, but I don't get why function mean() is used there.

For example, `CDF(70)` equals `0.623`, which is the probability of cumulative distribution at `70`. How does the `mean()` function show probability in this function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do a logical test, like `x <= a`, the result will be a boolean vector of `TRUE` and `FALSE` values. When you do math on boolean TRUE/FALSE values, `TRUE`s are treated as 1 and `FALSE`s are treated as 0. A common way to count the number of values of `x` that are less than or equal to `a` is `sum(x <= a)`. Similarly, if you wanted to know what proportion of `x` values are less than or equal to `a`, you could do `sum(x <= a) / length(x)`, which is the same as `mean(x <= a)`.